# Primal and Dual Solution not same

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose, we have following convex optimization problem:
$$\
\min_x\psi(x) \  \ s.t. \ \phi(x) \leq 0
$$
We can write the primal problem as:
$$\
\min_x\max_{\lambda\geq 0} \psi(x) + \lambda\phi(x)
$$
and the dual problem as:
$$\
\max_{\lambda\geq 0}\min_x \psi(x) + \lambda\phi(x)
$$
Let's say $(\bar x, \bar \lambda)$ is the solution to primal problem and $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ solution to dual problem. Assuming $\psi$ and $\phi$ are not strictly convex, primal solution need not be the same as dual solution i.e. $x^* \neq \bar x$ and $\lambda^* \neq \bar\lambda$. However strong duality tell us that, $\mathcal L (\bar x, \bar \lambda) = \mathcal L(x^*, \lambda^*)$. Can you point me to some interesting example for the same or give an intuition? I understand the problem does not have unique saddle point and hence this issue. I still have conceptual doubts, will $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ not satisfy the K.K.T conditions for the original constrained optimization problem?

**Edit:** I am confused because often people talk about methods for getting primal solution from the dual solution. [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04874.pdf) Page 56 (Applying Minimax theorem line) tells that the approximate solution is in the convex hull of dual iterates. Well my question is why not take the last iterate of dual?

Comment: One of the exercises in chapter 5 (on duality) of Boyd-Vandenberghe gives an example along the lines of what I think you are asking. pdf here: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf . I'm thinking of 5.23c).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I am still not able to see the direct correlation.

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood what you were asking... I thought you wanted an example where the primal and dual solutions have different values?

Comment: Yes, I wanted a example where Solutions itself are different i.e. two or more saddle points for $\mathcal L(x, \lambda)$ dual solution gives us a different saddle point and primal a different saddle point. Sorry for not making it explicit.

Comment: Both points will satisfy the KKT conditions. A simple example is if you take a constant function, e.g., $\psi(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KKT conditions of the primal and the dual problem are identical if the primal solution is attained.
The primal problem is:
$$\
\min_x\max_{\lambda\geq 0} \psi(x) + \lambda\phi(x) \qquad(P)
$$
Its KKT conditions are $\phi(x) \leq 0$ (primal feasibility), $\lambda\geq 0$ (dual feasibility) $\psi'(x) + \lambda \phi'(x)=0$ (stationarity) and $\lambda \phi(x)=0$ (complementarity).

The dual problem is:
$$\
\max_{\lambda\geq 0}\min_x \psi(x) + \lambda\phi(x) \qquad(D)
$$
which is equivalent to:
$$\
\max_{\lambda} \min_{y\geq 0, x} \psi(x) + \lambda\phi(x) + \lambda y \qquad(D)
$$
The stationarity condition is $\phi(x) + y = 0$ (i.e., $\phi(x)\leq 0$). The primal feasibility conditions are $\lambda \geq 0$ (as otherwise the value of $\min_{y\geq 0}$ is $-\infty$) and $\min_x \psi(x) + \lambda \phi(x)>-\infty$. For the latter, if the minimum is attained (i.e., the primal problem can be solved), you have $\psi'(x) + \lambda \phi'(x)=0$. The complementarity condition is $\lambda y = 0$ (which implies $\lambda \phi(x)=0$ via the stationarity condition).

Comment: Ahh so do you mean to say that the dual optimal solution is also exactly same or one of the primal optimal solution?

Comment: I am confused because often people talk about methods for getting primal solution from the dual solution. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04874.pdf Page 56 tells that the approximate solution is in the convex hull of dual iterates. Well my question is why not take the last iterate of dual?

Comment: @ShivTavker yes, the Lagrange multiplier of the dual is optimal to the primal problem. The algorithm in the paper does not discard old iterates, so the last iterate is not necessarily the one that satisfies the KKT conditions. Instead of considering all $X \succeq 0$ for which $tr X \leq K$, it considers a subset that is extended in every iteration. When the algorithm terminates, it's not necessarily the last added element that's binding.

Comment: Can you explain why "last iterate is not necessarily the one that satisfies the KKT conditions"? To make it more precise let's say we have $y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$ as the dual iterates. The paper solves $\min f(y)$ over $conv(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n)$ for the primal solution. Suppose if someone asks what's the dual solution instead, is it not $y_n$? What is it?

Comment: @ShivTavker It is not the last one because the separation oracle maintains the full set of hyperplanes and the binding hyperplane in the end might not be the last added one; $y$ is just a convex combination of the previously added ones. Page 59 explains how to obtain the primal solution.

Comment: Can you explain with an easier example for more clarity or an article which contains bit more detailed explanation? I guess this is very much binded to methods that use separation oracle. If in some problem we use only gradient descent and projection, we can take the last iterate or the average iterate right?

Comment: @ShivTavker Here is a simple example: $\min_{x \in [-10,10]} \max_{y \in [-1,1]} xy$. If you start with $y_0=1$, from $\min_{x \in [-10,10]} \max_{y\in\{1\}} xy$ you get $x=-10$, then you add $y_1=-1$, then from $\min_{x \in [-10,10]} \max_{y\in\{-1,1\}} xy$ you get $x=0$. The saddle point is $(0,0)$ even though $y_1=-1$ was the last value added.

Comment: I don't agree with this example:
1. $f(x, y) = xy$ is not convex
2. Every point is a saddle point for $f(x, y) = xy$.
3. Even when we minimize a function, the iterate at every point is not optimal. For e.g. In gradient descent we take a constant step size, the iterate returned is not optimal but the final iterate returned after many many iterations is indeed optimal.

Comment: @ShivTavker it is the lagrangian of $\min\{ 0 : x \leq 0 \}$ and the saddle point is unique.